# Trying to conenct to Azure Service Management API via a web app deployed in tomcat

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, keystore

I am not able to connect to Azure via a webapp deployed in tomcat.

I am getting the below error though i am sending the correct input for the keystore pwd.

"Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect"

Plz comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trustcacerts password was supplied wrongly ! Now it works

Answer (score 1):

When you try connecting to Windows Azure Management Portal, using Service Management API, the connectivity is created over SSL tunnel and a certificate is used to create the SSL tunnel.

I would suggest first that, it is not a Windows Azure specific problem, it is more of a Java/Tomcat related issue mainly happening because while selecting the certificate to create the SSL tunnel the code met with some problem.

To solve this problem, I can suggest the following:

- In your VM/Physical machine, where Tomcat web application is running try to locate the physical keystore file first and delete it.
- After that try creating keystore with correct password and setup that password properly in your Tomcat configuration